# paper-icon-button (Ploymer 1.0) goes into weird focussed state on touch devices

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

If you tap on paper-icon-button on its sides (i.e. not exactly in the centre), it goes into pressed state and "on-tap" event is not called. This is easily reproducible on chrome browser on touch devices.

[image]

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I recommend you file a bug on the paper-icon-button repo https://github.com/polymer/paper-icon-button

Comment: Done that already (https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-icon-button/issues/47). Thanks!